# How to add Items to recyclerView after scanning QR Code dynamically

Tags: android

> 1.On Floating Button click QR Code is scan result is `**acc123**` and it's going to call JSON data from web service which is **`View_ID='v1'`**.Which is working properly.
>
> 2.What I have to do is on next scan result is `**acc124**` and it's going to call JSON data from web service which is **`View_ID = "v2"`**. I want it to store in the same recycler View as well as bind it to offline.
>
> 3. But, At this point when I scan new QR Code all previous data is gone and its call JSON data and store its View.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Menu menu;
    TextView qrCode;
    private static final String TAG = "QR CODE";
    List<GetAdapter> GetAdapter1;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    
    //qr code scanner object
    private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //intializing scan object
        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        GetAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview3);
        qrCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Category);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    
    }

    /**
     * Initializing collapsing toolbar
     * Will show and hide the toolbar title on scroll
     */
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                qrScan.initiateScan();
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with QR code scan action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    //Getting the scan results
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                qrCode.setText(result.getContents());

                JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();

                //if qr contains data

                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }


    /** JSON CALL */
    public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {

        final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL: " + Constants.GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL + qrCode.getText().toString());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                Constants.GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL + qrCode.getText().toString(), null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        GetAdapter GetAdapter2 = new GetAdapter();

                        Log.d("Request", response.toString());
                        try {
                            response.getString("View_ID");
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("View");
                            GetAdapter2.setViewId(response.getString("View_ID"));
                            GetAdapter2.setMAC_QR_Code(qrCode.getText().toString());

                            JSONObject id = (JSONObject) array.get(0);

                            JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(array);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.getString("View_ID"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.getString("View"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mProgressDialog.hide();
                        GetAdapter1.add(GetAdapter2);


                    }


                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("Request", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                mProgressDialog.hide();
            }
        });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetAdapter1, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
      }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            GetAdapterButton GetAdapter2 = new GetAdapterButton();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //  GetAdapter2.setViewId(json.getString(JSON_VIEW_ID));

               //  GetAdapter2.setButtonId(json.getString(Constants.JSON_BUTTON_ID));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           // GetAdapter1.add(GetAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetAdapter1, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }

}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    String MAC_QR_Code;
    List<com.test.boariot.adapter.GetAdapter> GetAdapter;
    ImageLoader imageLoader1;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetAdapter> GetAdapter, Context context){
        super();
        this.GetAdapter = GetAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) {
        final GetAdapter GetAdapter1 =  GetAdapter.get(position);
        Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(GetAdapter1.getViewId());
        MAC_QR_Code=(GetAdapter1.getMAC_QR_Code());
        Viewholder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(Viewholder.overflow);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return GetAdapter.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
        public TextView ImageCategory;
        public ImageView networkImageView, overflow ;
        public View view;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;

            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Id) ;
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);

            networkImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeholder) ;
            networkImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    // item clicked
                    // Start NewActivity.class
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                            NextActivity.class);
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onClick: "+MAC_QR_Code);
                    myIntent.putExtra("MAC_QR_Code",MAC_QR_Code);

                    v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**What I want is to store previous data to recycler view as well as add new data to it.**
I hope I make my point clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `GetAdapter`  is not an adapter, it's a plain Java object. Try to follow object naming conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only setup the adapter like  this **once** in onCreate.

```
adapterData = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(adapterData, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
```

Anytime you add to the Arraylist, you must call `recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for anything to be displayed

Comment: To store it to offline is storing in SQLite is the only way or any thing else can work.

Comment: You can also implement an `add()` method in the adapter class to combine that Arraylist addition with a notify

Comment: Sqlite is one option. Realm database is another popular library

Comment: Which one is better (easy). I use SQLite. But it's tricky to use it.

Comment: Sqlite can be easy with the right libraries . https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create a new RecyclerViewAdapter every time.

Just write a method in your adapter to add objects to it instead only allow to pass in the list via constructor. Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add the barcode result to an Arraylist and call the adapter, if you want to remove, remove the result from your arraylist